# Hibernate is creating one more table in addition to the required table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
@GenericGenerator(name="hilo-gen",strategy="hilo")

@CollectionId(columns={@Column(name="address_id")},
                generator="hilo-gen",
                type=@Type(type= "int")
            )
@JoinTable(name="friends_addresses",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Collection <Address> getFriendsAddresses() {
    return friendsAddresses;
}
```

On saving a List of Address (`@Embeddable`), I see that hibernate created one more table (hibernate_unique_key) in MySQL. Is there any strategy that will avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernates uses an additional table to generate unique ids if you don't enable auto incrementing ids.